# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRING

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka-http, typesafe

when i try to sbt build :
sbt run -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.keyStore.type="JKS" -Dhttps.keyStore.password="password" -Dhttps.keyStore.path=/cert/https-example.jks

it shows error :

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[error] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Cannot load SSL context
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:116)
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:39)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.sslContext$lzycompute(AkkaHttpServer.scala:245)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.sslContext(AkkaHttpServer.scala:244)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$httpsServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:260)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$httpsServerBinding$1$adapted(AkkaHttpServer.scala:255)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRING
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:175)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:194)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:251)
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:37)
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTPS on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9443
[error] com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRING
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:164)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:175)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:194)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:251)
[error]     at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:37)
[error]     at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:30)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[error]     at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:116)
[error]     at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:39)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.sslContext$lzycompute(AkkaHttpServer.scala:245)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.sslContext(AkkaHttpServer.scala:244)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$Http1Encrypted$2(AkkaHttpServer.scala:530)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.Http1Encrypted$lzycompute(AkkaHttpServer.scala:522)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.Http1Encrypted(AkkaHttpServer.scala:520)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.<init>(AkkaHttpServer.scala:564)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:665)
[error]     at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider.createServer(AkkaHttpServer.scala:663)
[error]     at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.$anonfun$mainDev$1(DevServerStart.scala:311)
[error]     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:22)
[error]     at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:76)
[error]     at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevOnlyHttpsMode(DevServerStart.scala:40)
[error]     at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevOnlyHttpsMode(DevServerStart.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error]     at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:311)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:100)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:83)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3(PlayRun.scala:107)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3$adapted(PlayRun.scala:67)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / run for the full output
[error] (Compile / run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed 06-Apr-2022, 10:10:14 PM
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Stopping Akka HTTP server...
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Terminating server binding for /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9443
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Running provided shutdown stop hooks
```

I tried what i know but i can't find the correct answer. if you know anything about it please help me..!. why it doesn't take the path? is I did anything wrong?

Comment: "path has type OBJECT rather than STRING" so maybe put quotes round the path?

Comment: @Tim yes, I've tried but it still shows same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the correct way to do this, i don't know why `application.conf` not working but adding the data in `build.sbt` helped me to solve this error.

```
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.https.port" -> "9443"
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.http.port" -> "disabled"
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.https.keyStore.type" -> "JKS"
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.https.keyStore.password" -> "password"
PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.https.keyStore.path" -> "https-example.jks"
```

The data added  `build.sbt` so there is no need to add data in `sbt run`